# Creating automated tests using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api, unit-testing

I'm creating a lib using the Google Earth Engine Python API.
I need to test this script in travis CI. When I'm launching the unittest into my env it work but when I push to Github the test fail because the virtual env doesn't know my Google credential.

Is there a way to add my Earth Engine credential into my test environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously here, the big question will be :
**How to authenticate programmatically to the Earth engine API ?**
Once you've done that, it's pretty much strait forward to use your standard test suit

### Set up

to authenticate, you will need to have a Google Cloud Project and enable the Earth Engine API for that project.

I assume that you are already registered to Earth engine, if it's not the case follow this link : https://signup.earthengine.google.com/

So first create a cloud project : https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate

Then enable your Earth Engine account in your cloud project https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/earthengine.googleapis.com

You can manage the service accounts for your Cloud project by going to the Cloud Console menu and selecting IAM & Admin > [Service accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/). (Choose the project if prompted.)

To create a new service account, click the [+ CREATE SERVICE ACCOUNT](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/create) link.

Once you have a service account, click the menu for that account, then Create key > JSON. Download the JSON key file.

### transform your key into a variable

Usually CI services use variables to deal with private key

Here you will `transform your private_key.json` file inta a encoded string that you'll upload to your CI.

```py
import json
import base64

with open('ee_api_key.json') as jsonfile:
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
    datastr = json.dumps(data)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(datastr.encode())

print(encoded)
```

copy past the content of the `encoded` variable into your CI system (travis CI, CircleCI...)

### Usage

in your file, start with the following code:

```py
# only use the key when I'm in my test env
if 'EE_PRIVATE_KEY' in os.environ:
    # key need to be decoded in a file to work 
    content = base64.b64decode(os.environ['EE_PRIVATE_KEY']).decode()
    with open('ee_private_key.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
    
    # connection to the service account
    service_account = 'my-service-account@...gserviceaccount.com'
    credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, 'ee_private_key.json')
    ee.Initialize(credentials)

else:
    ee.Initialize()
```

Then you'll be ready to go

### troubleshooting

(2020-11-27) the `six` lib is not installed properly by EarthEngine API so if you bump into the following error :

> AttributeError: module 'six.moves' has no attribute 'collections_abc'

Then force the version in your `requirements.txt` as `six>=1.15.0`

### notes

This answer is a sum-up of 2 documentations pages of Google API, feel free to have a look for more specific information :
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/earthengine_cloud_project_setup#create-a-cloud-project
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/service_account