# Which project am I running? Earth Engine / Google Cloud

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-cloud

I am running an Earth Engine data pipeline in a Jupyter notebook. I have set the project in the command line with `!earthengine set_project my-proj`. I simply want to check which project the subsequent code will be billed to and run from.

I have tried this:

```
from google.cloud.resourcemanager import ProjectsClient

ProjectsClient().search_projects()
```

Which gives me a list of all projects I have access to, **but whether or not they are enabled is ambiguous.**

> I have also referred to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377222/creating-automated-tests-using-google-earth-engine-python-api), [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435479/get-the-list-of-my-projects-in-earthengine), and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422580/earth-engine-understanding-the-new-cloud-project-feature) questions,
> but nobody seems to have the same urge to confirm which cloud project
> they are using.

**How do I confirm which Google Cloud Project I am using to run subsequent Earth Engine code?**